# Filter DataFrame plus show me data where you can not filter

Tags: python, pandas, filter

imagin i have this Dataframe,

```
      MNR  MINM_x  MINM_y
0   62614     7.0    10.0
1   62614     7.0    20.0
2   62614     7.0    30.0
3  67624B     1.0     1.0
4  67624B     1.0    10.0
```

Now i want to filter where MINM_x  == MINM_x  so i did this

```
df_innerfinal1 =df_innerfinal[df_innerfinal.MINM_x == df_innerfinal.MINM_y]
```

the result is now this

```
      MNR  MINM_x  MINM_y
3  67624B     1.0     1.0
```

but i want this

so if there is no posibilty to filter on MNR Show me the data where you can not filter

```
      MNR  MINM_x  MINM_y
0   62614     7.0    10.0
1   62614     7.0    20.0
2   62614     7.0    30.0
3  67624B     1.0     1.0
```

have you any ideas???

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `df_innerfinal1 =df_innerfinal[df_innerfinal.MINM_x != df_innerfinal.MINM_y]
`

Comment: sry i want that MINM_x  and MINM_y is matching, and like you can see at mnr:  62614  if the can not match show me still data